# not able to compile a libcurl program in C

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to run a libcurl program, but I am getting the following error:

fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Can anyone give me step by step instructions to install libcurl on a linux machine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bdonlan: sorry...i am working on linux system....ubuntu 11.04... my bad

Comment: tip: Provide the command(s) that you're using to compile, the code (or a small representation) and the error that you got.

Comment: @razpeitia: i am using command "gcc curl.c -l curl" for compilation, the error is in the question above.

Comment: Install [libcurl-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libcurl-dev) and you'll get your header.

Comment: Are you unable to compile, or unable to run? Anyway, you can search by file name in `apt-file` (optional package) or at http://packages.ubuntu.com/; the file you are looking for exists in multiple packages called libcurl4-*-dev where * can be gnutls or nss or openssl (I would get the openssl one).

Answer (score 4):

I found this result on Google, but I'm using Fedora, and had to use this command:

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
```

Hopefully, this will help someone who is trying to do what I just did.

Answer (score 1):

@ compile time linkit

```
gcc -Wall hellWeb.c -lcurl -o helloWeb
```